# Adding FilteredList and SortedList to make a Search bar in Javafx returns java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to make a Search bar using JFXTextField in Javafx8. But when I add `FilteredList` and `SortedList` in my Code, The Application no longer run and Output shows the following Exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: file:/C:/Users/Zed%20and%20White/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Project_EMS/dist/run1317715357/Project_EMS.jar!/project_ems/FrontEnd.fxml:22

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at project_ems.Project_EMS.start(Project_EMS.java:23)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.<init>(TransformationList.java:65)
at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.<init>(FilteredList.java:66)
at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.<init>(FilteredList.java:87)
at project_ems.FrontEndController.<init>(FrontEndController.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 17 more
Exception running application project_ems.Project_EMS
```

I have followed this method [Create Search TextField to Search in a Javafx table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317837/create-search-textfield-field-to-search-in-a-javafx-tableview)

Here's my Code:

**ObservableList:**

```
private ObservableList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> EListingData;
```

**Block of Code that Uses the Above Observable List:**

```
private void LoadEListingData(){
    try {
        DBE.resultSet = DBE.statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Exam");
        EListingData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while (DBE.resultSet.next()) {                
            EListingData.add(new DataHandler_ExamsListing(DBE.resultSet.getInt("ExamID"),DBE.resultSet.getString("ExamName"),DBE.resultSet.getString("ExamDate"),DBE.resultSet.getString("ExamComment")));
        }
        EListingTable.setItems(EListingData);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}
```

**FilteredList and SortedList (Both are Global):**

```
private final FilteredList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> FilteredData = new FilteredList<>(EListingData);
private final SortedList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> sortedData = new SortedList<>(FilteredData);
```

**SearchBar FXML:**

```
@FXML // fx:id="SearchExam_Elisting"
private JFXTextField SearchExam_Elisting; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
```

**ActionEvent on SearchBar:**

```
    @FXML
private void SearchExamList(ActionEvent event) {

    SearchExam_Elisting.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    FilteredData.setPredicate(DataHandler_ExamsListing -> {
        if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

        if (DataHandler_ExamsListing.getExamName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
      });      
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(EListingTable.comparatorProperty());
    EListingTable.setItems(sortedData);
    System.out.println("DOne");
}
```

if I comment out `FilteredList` and `SortedList` and the `ActionEvent`, The App runs smoothly.

Please help me resolve this Issue. **Thanks!**

Comment: @fabian Done Editing

Comment: How is `EListingData` initialized and when is this done?

Comment: @fabian `private ObservableList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> EListingData;`

Comment: @fabian `EListingData` is Initialized right above the `Filetered and Sorted Lists`

Comment: `private ObservableList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> EListingData;` just declares the field. It does not initialize it (= assigns a value). Is there some initializer block/constructor that is supposed to assign a value to this field? The default value for uninitialized fields of non-primitive types is `null` which is passed to the constructor of `FilteredList` according to the stacktrace.

Comment: @fabian please have a look at the Edited question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *"Both are global"*. The closest thing to a global scope would be `static` fields and none of the fields is declared as `static`.

But as for the issue in the question:

You're initializing the `FilteredData` field when declaring it which results in the assignment being executed even before a constructor would be executed. This means there is no way the `LoadEListingData` is executed before the assignment

```
FilteredData = new FilteredList<>(EListingData);
```

for this reason `EListingData` is still `null` at that time. This is not allowed though.

You need change the time this field is initialized, e.g. to after loading the data using the `LoadEListingData`.

Alternatively you could initialize the field with a empty `ObservableList` and fill this list later when the `LoadEListingData` method is called:

```
private final ObservableList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> EListingData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private final FilteredList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> FilteredData = new FilteredList<>(EListingData);
private final SortedList<DataHandler_ExamsListing> sortedData = new SortedList<>(FilteredData);

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    EListingTable.setItems(sortedData);
}

private void LoadEListingData(){
    List<DataHandler_ExamsListing> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        // prepare data for insert using single update
        DBE.resultSet = DBE.statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Exam"); // directly accessing static fields of a different class is a terrible idea since it violates the information hiding principle
        while (DBE.resultSet.next()) {                
            data.add(new DataHandler_ExamsListing(DBE.resultSet.getInt("ExamID"),DBE.resultSet.getString("ExamName"),DBE.resultSet.getString("ExamDate"),DBE.resultSet.getString("ExamComment")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Never just ignore an exception unless it's expected
        return;
    }
    // update data
    EListingData.setAll(data);
}
```